# Powerapps - Unable to change Toggle on separate screen

Tags: toggle, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to use toggles on an inactive screen as a replacement for functions (and thus help code reuse), however I'm stuck as my toggle won't activate unless I visit the page it's on. I found plenty of working examples online but somehow can't get it to work for me.

### Overview:

I have a button on **screen1** and a toggle on **screen2**.

During my button's `OnSelect` event, a variable `varSendData` is being set to `true` like so:

```
Set (varSendData, true)
```

[image]

The toggle has its `Default` property set to `varSendData`.

The `OnCheck` property of the toggle contains the code to be executed:

```
Notify("This works")
```

### Problem:

While the variable `varSendData` is correctly being set to `true`, nothing happens while I'm on the **screen1** with the button. Only when I visit the **screen2** with the toggle (even if in edit mode only) does the toggle change state and execute the code in the `OnCheck` property. I tried using the `OnChange` property of the toggle, however that has the same effect/limitation.

Furthermore, if I set the variable (`varSendData`) back to `false` before visiting **screen2** then nothing happens from which I conclude that the toggle is only triggered (changed) if the page it's on is visible/active.

Any ideas on how I could get the toggle to change state even if I'm not screen2? Or any other ideas on how I could reuse the same code from different screens?

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation of the method the actual code is calling.  In order to allow the HTML to refresh from this **"Notify("This Works")**.  You would need to also have a function that refreshes the HTML in the screen your currently viewing.

I was able to get this to work by adding a label and setting its text property to be **If(Toggle6.Value = true, "yes", "no")**.

Literally adding this in allowed the notification to pop up.  Nothing extra.
[image]
[image]